# How to test data transport between two local sockets

Tags: sockets, c++11, testing, automated-tests

I have two classes `ReceiverSocket` receiving data and `SenderSocket` sending data.

```
 explicit SenderSocket(const std::string &receiver_ip, const int port_num);
```

In debug modle, I pass receiver_ip = "127.0.0.1". Here is a method called `SendPacket` and its declaration：

```
 void SendPacket(const std::vector<unsigned char> &data);
```

Similar to `SenderSocket`, `ReceiverSocket` can receive data on a port.

```
explicit ReceiverSocket(int port_number);

const std::vector<unsigned char> GetPacket() const;

//The method returns true on success, false otherwise. 
const bool BindSocketToListen() const;
```

In order to test these two classes, I have to create two executable files , one for `SenderSocket` another for `ReceiverSocket`.

**Is there any way to write a test for data transport ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For manual tests, have you tried this using WireShark? This topic explains how:
https://superuser.com/questions/508623/how-can-i-see-127-0-0-1-traffic-on-windows-using-wireshark?answertab=votes#tab-top

Another option which might be more suitable for automated testing, could be to create a third executable which acts as a 'man in the middle'. Both of your executables will have to communicate thought this third executable, which just passes all data through, but also allows you to listen and validate the data.
Of course you could also use a testing framework to run the 'man-in-the-middle pass-through server'.